# Running application in netbeans results in NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, java-me

While I'm running a simple application in my Netbeans 6.9.1,it's showing "task running, click for details" for a long time .and also there is an error "unexpected exception" in the bottom of the netbeans when I'm  clicking that:

```
NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tools.ant.util.FileUtils.getFileUtils()Lorg/apache/tools/ant/util/FileUtils;
```

This error is coming. Few days before this application executed well, but now this error for all applications.The main error is it's not running,but it's showing "running" for a long time..

Answer (score 2):

You should move to the newer or at least stable version of netbeans (from what I can see you are using a beta version '6.9beta'. Download the latest stable release of netbeans and open your project there.

Comment: No,I'm using 6.9.1..not beta version..before this i have used that only..but now once i clicked on that error next time it;s not visible..at the same time project is still running running only..

Comment: For some reason its looking for smth in your 6.9beta directory, I would recommend removing your '.netbeans' directory and installation alltogether and do clean reinstall, unless you have a good reason not to.